# Mysql table join records from 2 tables but get all records from main table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a students table and a results table, both with studentId. There can be one or no results for each student in the results table. There can be more but with parameters i just want one or none, but i still want all the students even if they have no result, results are multiple columns pivoted. What join do i need, i've tried them all. Or do i need a subquery?

Thanks, sql below returns only students with results, assessment values, i want all students in classId 3 even if they don't have and entry. Its going in a data grid so i can insert/edit assessment results

```
select s.studentId, r.resultID as ThisResultID, r.*, arv.*, u.fullname as TeacherName from (Results R
left join AssessmentResultValues arv on r.resultID = arv.resultID)
left join users u on u.userID = R.userID
left join students as s on s.studentId = R.studentId
where arv.resulttypeID = 32
and assessmentID = 181
and yearID = 21
and Month = 0
and Term = 0
and Week = 0
and Semester = 1
and s.studentClassId = 3
order by dateentered
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the students table first in the list of tables after FROM. When you do a left join, all records will be included from the first table, but from the second table you will only get records matching the join condition. In your query, the students table is the second table in a left join, and that is why all students are not included in the result.